# redirect emails from one domain to another

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, dns-zone

i have 2 domains.
domain.com and domain.org

all my emails are at domain.org
so i have user1@domain.org
user2@domain.org
etc...

i want that if some have a mistake and he sends email to user1@domain.com there will be a redirect or something like that.

is it possible on a zone level with mx or txt record? i don't want to have rule for each one of the emails

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This can be done at the zone level, but also requires configuration of the MTA on the receiving machine. Basically, you set the MX record for `domain.com` to the same value(s) as the MX for `domain.org`, and then you tell that server to accept mail for both domains. I do this through the `/etc/sendmail/local-host-names` file, using Sendmail, but I'm sure there are other ways to do it. If Sendmail isn't your preferred MTA, you'll have to look up the equivalent methodology.

Comment: This is spot on, so hopefully the OP realizes this and also realizes that it technically is MORE work than have a forwarding rule for each mailbox over on domain.com.  However, it also assumes that he is running the mail server and not simply having hosted email on the .org domain as well.

Comment: It's about the same amount of work for two domains, it's actually less work for three or more domains, as long as all the user IDs are the same. And yes, it does assume it's a self-hosted mail solution on both (or all) domains.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to set up just with txt and mx.
I would suggest trying to set up a catch-all email somewhere that will forward all incoming emails by wildcard rules like:
*@adomain.com -> *@bdomain.com

Can't mention any service solution because I'm afraid to be blocked from answering at all.